# How can I listening "controller board" with indy 10 tcpip?

Tags: tcp, indy10, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a code in Visual Basic, that have a timer and listening a tcpip stream. I´m try to code it in deplhi, but I have problems.

I get connect sucessful in board with tcpip like this : IdTCPClient1.Connect;

Board tcpip is 192.168.0.180, port 2000, my server is 192.168.0.30.

I´m try this code :

```
procedure TForm1.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
var StrStream: TMemoryStream;
begin

  if IdTCPClient1.Connected then
    begin
      StrStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Connected then
        IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStream(StrStream,-1,false);

      Memo1.Lines.Add('hello');
    end;

end;
```

The problem is, in line IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStream(StrStream,-1,false); the application stop, no error, no message and I don´t undestand.

VB code

```
    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

        Try

            If tcp1.Available > 1 Then
                Dim leitura As NetworkStream = tcp1.GetStream
                Dim bytes(tcp1.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                leitura.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcp1.ReceiveBufferSize))
                returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
                txtSerial1.AppendText(returndata)

            End If

            If tcp2.Available > 1 Then
                Dim leitura As NetworkStream = tcp2.GetStream
                Dim bytes(tcp2.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                leitura.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcp2.ReceiveBufferSize))
                returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
                txtSerial2.AppendText(returndata)
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling the IOHandler's `ReadStream()` method, setting `AByteCount=-1` and `AReadUntilDisconnect=False` as you are tells `ReadStream()` to expect the incoming data to be preceded by a multi-byte integer (either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the IOHandler's `LargeStream` property) that specifies the number of subsequent bytes in the data, and it then waits for that many bytes to actually arrive. Is that what the server's data actually looks like? I doubt it, because that is not what your VB code is expecting.

Using the IOHandler's `ReadBytes()` method with `AByteCount=-1` would be a closer equivalent to your VB code than using the `ReadStream()` method, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bytes: TIdBytes;
begin
  if IdTCPClient1.Connected then
  begin
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Bytes, -1);
    // use Bytes as needed...
    Memo1.Lines.Add('hello');
  end;
end;
```

Also, keep in mind that Indy uses blocking socket I/O by default. You really shouldn't perform blocking operations in the main UI thread.  You should move your reading logic to a separate worker thread instead.  Or, at the very least, make sure you set a small `ReadTimeout` on the `TIdTCPClient` so `ReadBytes()` does not block the UI for very long.